# Is there any way to call a closure inside a spawned thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a function:

```
fn awesome_function<F>(v: Vec<u64>, f: F)
    where F: Fn(u64) -> String
{ /* ... */ }
```

Is there any way to call that passed in function inside a spawned thread? Something like:

```
...
thread::spawn(move || f(1));
...
```

I've tried a few different ways and I get an error `error: the trait core::marker::Send is not implemented for the type F [E0277]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely. The main thing you have to do is restrict `F` to also be `Send`:

```rust
use std::thread;

fn awesome_function<F>(v: Vec<u64>, f: F) -> String
    where F: Fn(u64) + Send + 'static
{
    thread::spawn(move || f(1));
    unimplemented!()
}

fn main() {}
```

You also need to restrict it to `'static`, as also required by `thread::spawn`.

Comment: Wow ... thanks! verify fast and answered the question perfectly.